# How to install private npm package using release hosted on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, npm

Currently, I create a release and add a deploy key on GitHub, then I add an entry to `.ssh/config` and install the package using the `git+ssh` protocol.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host react-hashlink
HostName github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/react-hashlink

$ npm install git+ssh://git@react-hashlink:sunknudsen/react-hashlink.git#v0.0.1
```

This works, but feels like a hack... is there a cleaner alternative?